# In India, what phone location tracking may or must network providers do to aid police?

Tags: police, consumer-protection, india, phone, police-power

For android phones in India-

1). suppose if a phone was moving around within few miles radious for few days and it was turned on several times in that duration. **But now the phone is turned off permanently and only after phone is turned off police starts to try to track the phone for the first time** using only the mobile no which was being used by that phone when it was turned on in last few days. So does law allow network provider to store location history of that phone
and also are police allowed to get all the locations where that phone were in those last few days ?

2). Also if that phone's user **turns off permanently or throws away the phone** and take a new phone and inserts the same sim card in that new phone, and **only after that if police starts to try to track using that mobile no for the first time,** does law allow network providers to store location infos of a past phone of a sim and are police even allowed to get all the location infos about where that old phone were for last few days before it was thrown away? in India, Law allows network providers to how long retain location infos of a cell phone and how much and does law allow police to get those location infos and how much?

Comment: Why do you think the OS of the phone is relevant?

Comment: I'm a noob, but i heard somewhere iPhone can b tracked even when it's switched off or don't have any sim inserted where android phones become untraceable bricks

Comment: OS will affect the technical ability to track the phone, but it's unlikely to affect the legality of tracking. (I'm not familiar with Indian law, but I would be very surprised if the law allows tracking only of iPhones or only of Android phones.)